# Having redirect issue

Tags: php, redirect, header

I'm using directory  structure  (for redirecting from other pages for example after succesful registration) with `header("Location: ../../../index.php");` function. It works in local server well but in remote one getting error message

Now, If I put `localhost/` it will work in my local webserver but not in remote one. If I put the exact address of the web page then it will not work in my local server. How can I generate websites (main pages) URL with PHP? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

This will take you to the homedirectory of the server (note, if running locally you need to have your virtualhosts configured correctly but not hard to do).

If you need to direct to a specific directory or file, just add after the '/' above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$cwd = dirname(__FILE__);
header("Location: $cwd/../../../index.php");
```

Comment: $cwd is the parent directory of the current file, right? `header("Location: $cwd/../../../index.php");` what will do? i don't understand

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt ... try it 1st, then complain.

Comment: i want to understand first then try.